# C how do I know when the child process in background ends?

Tags: process, background, wait, pid

I'm trying to make my own shell in unix.
I want to make child process run in background with adding PID to jobList. And when it ends, I want it to delete PID from jobList. But I don't understand how should I know when the child process in background finishes?

```
        int childPid,endPid;
        if(addJob(jobs,childPid = fork(),0,"fork()") >= 0){
            if(childPid == 0){
                printf("Child Process Running...\n");

                execl("/bin/sleep","sleep","5",(char*) 0);

                deleteJob(jobs,childPid);
                exit(0);
            }

            else if(childPid > 0){
                if(!info->bg){
                    int count=1;
                    //waitpid(childPid,NULL,0);

                    while(endPid!=childPid){
                        sleep(1);
                        endPid=waitpid(childPid,NULL,WNOHANG);
                        //printf("%d:%d\n",endPid,childPid);
                        printf("%d\n",count++);
                    }

                    printf("child process ended.\n");
                    deleteJob(jobs,childPid);
                }
                else{
                    printf("child process runs in background.. \n");    
                    //sleep(1);



                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use one of the variants of the wait() function to receive and handle a signal when a child process changes state: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wait.html

Comment: then how do I get my prompt back while the wait() checking the child process to change its state? Do you mean I should define SIG?

Comment: Yes, you need to define a signal handler for SIGCHLD. In that signal handler, you would call one of the variants of wait().